# NaN as prediction on sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I've coded a chatbot with sklearn in python, I created a dataset like this:

| text | labels |
| --- | --- |
| hola | greeting |
| hey! | greeting |
| buenos días | greeting |
| buenas noches | greeting |
| beings tardes | greeting |
| chao | byes |
| hasta luego | byes |
| hasta la próxima | byes |

First, I tested the chatbot with only two classes, and then I added more:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| que ta? | question1 |
| como estas? | question1 |
| como te encuentras? | question1 |
| que tel? | question1 |
| como te llamas | question2 |

It predicts the tag correctly, but it didn't choose the response from the responses file

Responses file:

| greeting | byes | question1 | question2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hola, que tal estas? | Hasta luego, pasalo bien! | Bien y tu? | Hey! Me llamo Albert |
| Hey! Que tal vals? | Chao! | Pasando el rato! |  |
| Buenos dias | Hasta la próxima |  |  |
| Buenas tardes |  |  |  |
| Buenas noches |  |  |  |

And here is what the chatbot responses:

[image]

As you can see, the bot predicts ok the tag
The problem only happends sometimes with random inputs.

Here is a code to reproduce the problem:

```
#Model & Pipeline

model = LogisticRegression(C=25, penalty="l2", solver="saga" , max_iter=2000)
pipeline = Pipeline([("tfidf" , vectorizer) , ("clf" , model)])

pipeline.fit(X_train , X_test)

prediction = pipeline.predict(y_train)

print("Test Pred: " , prediction)

while True:
  usr_inp = input("Tú: ")
  writed_data = [usr_inp] #Convert the input string to list

  #Temporal-writing file
  with file:     
    write = csv.writer(file) 
    write.writerow(writed_data) #Write the input

  dat = pd.read_csv("file.csv") #Read the temporal-file

  X_predict = dat #temporal-file as variable X_predict

  prediction = pipeline.predict(X_predict)#Make prediction
  print("Prediction: " , prediction)
clean_tag = str(prediction).replace("[" , "").replace("]" , "").replace("'" , "")   #Clean the output tag
  response = random.choice(responses_data[clean_tag]) #Make a response

  print("Albert: " , response)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem,
It happens because of the dataset:

| greeting | byes | question1 | question2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hola, que tal estas? | Hasta luego, pasalo bien! | Bien y tu? | Hey! Me llamo Albert |
| Hey! Que tal vals? | Chao! | Pasando el rato! |  |
| Buenos dias | Hasta la próxima |  |  |
| Buenas tardes |  |  |  |
| Buenas noches |  |  |  |

As you can see, there are blanks.
To solve the problem, you have to write something in this spaces.